# Is root/higher privlieges required to receive an answer from DNS

Tags: python, linux, sockets, dns

Good day,

I am not sure where I should place this question  , I am learning about DNS and how it works and as I understand I send a request out on UDP port 53 to a server and the host should respond to me on that port correct?

Here is a script that I am working with and it works and accurately describes the DNS message query and usage and even gets a DNS answer back for me.

How is this possible if it cannot listen on port 53 with out having root on a system?

**DNS PACKET DETAILS**

```
;DNS HEADER;
   ; AA AA - ID
   ; 01 00 - Query parameters
   ; 00 01 - Number of questions
   ; 00 00 - Number of answers
   ; 00 00 - Number of authority records
   ; 00 00 - Number of additional records
   ; DNS QUESTION --
   ; 07 - 'example' has length 7, ;so change this to be the length of domain ; keep in ming there are not '.' in the question.
   ; 65 - e
   ; 78 - x
   ; 61 - a
   ; 6D - m
   ; 70 - p
   ; 6C - l
   ; 65 - e

   ; 03 - subdomain '.com'  length 03  ; change this to be the length of type.

   ; 63 - c
   ; 6F - o
   ; 6D - m
```

**CODE :**

```
import binascii
import socket


def send_udp_message(message, address, port):
    """send_udp_message sends a message to UDP server

    message should be a hexadecimal encoded string
    """
    message = message.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
    server_address = (address, port)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        sock.sendto(binascii.unhexlify(message), server_address)
        data, _ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    finally:
        sock.close()
    return binascii.hexlify(data).decode("utf-8")


def format_hex(hex):
    """format_hex returns a pretty version of a hex string"""
    octets = [hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex), 2)]
    pairs = [" ".join(octets[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(octets), 2)]
    return "\n".join(pairs)


message = "AA AA 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 " \
"07 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01 00 01"

response = send_udp_message(message, "8.8.8.8", 53)
print(format_hex(response))
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
aa aa
81 80
00 01
00 01
00 00
00 00
07 65
78 61
6d 70
6c 65
03 63
6f 6d
00 00
01 00
01 c0
0c 00
01 00
01 00
00 32
98 00
04 5d
b8 d8
22
```

If you look at the last four bytes you'll see that this is the IP for example.com in hex **5db8d822**

You can go here to check it out.
[HEX to IP converter Online](https://ncalculators.com/digital-computation/ip-address-hex-decimal-binary.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your source port is not port 53. User processes are allocated outbound port numbers above 1023, which are unprivileged.

A simple synchronous Python DNS client will basically block and hold the same port open until the server responds. The IP packet you send contains the information that the server needs in order to know where to reply (this is in the headers of the IP packet itself, before the DNS query payload).

Comment: Shouldn't the response come in on 53 though ?